# Adding headers below search controller in table view

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently having problems figuring out how I should implement this:
[link to interface design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF1a8.png)

I currently have a search controller programmed into my table view, and would like to insert a header as shown in the image between the search controllers and the table view cells.

I'm lost as to how I should implement this because most tutorials show having the headers above the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the search bar, the header and the table as separate components.

Or you could add a tableview/section header, but in that case upon scrolling you the header may disappear.

Comment: I tried having the search bar, header and table as separate components, but it involved using the search display controller which was deprecated in iOS8. Do you know if there's anyway to link a storyboard UISearchBar component to the search bar controller that was programmed?

Comment: I do not understand you. UISearchBar was not deprecated. The way it works is that you have a delegate with methods similar to those of a textfield. On them you should filter the results of your tableview.